# MySQL database connection to a c++ win32 project

Tags: c++, mysql, sql, winapi, visual-c++

I'm trying to connect a MySQL database to my c++ Win32 project for school. I already did the set up of visual studio, all the include files and directories as my professor told me, this is how she told me to do so after installing MySQL and connector of course:

- Windows Visual Studio

1) If you use Microsoft Visual Studio as your c++ editor.
a. Go to Solution Explorer and right click the project and find the 
project properties. In the Configuration Properties, find C/C++ and 
click on General and then edit Additional Include Directories in the 
right frame by typing the directory of header files of these three 
libraries, such as the include directory of MySQL Server 5.5, the 
include directory of MySQL Connector C++ 1.1.3, and the directory 
of Boost 1.55.0. 
b. In the tree view of Project Properties diagram, open Linker, 
General, Additional Library Directories. Add the ${MySQL}/lib/opt 
directory into the Additional Library Directories text field and add $
{MySQL_Connector}/lib directory into the Additional Library 
Directories text field.

After that I compiled and everything was fine and then I added the code for establishing a connection, which is inside the event handler of a button click.My #include statements look like this:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "AddBook.h"
#include "afxdialogex.h"
#include "resource.h"
#include <windows.system.h>
#include <mysql.h>

#include <mysql_connection.h> 
#include <mysql_driver.h> 

#include <cppconn/driver.h> 
#include <cppconn/exception.h> 
#include <cppconn/resultset.h> 
#include <cppconn/statement.h>

using namespace std;
using namespace sql;
using namespace sql::mysql;
```

So her example of connection was this (with all the include files above):

```
int main(void) 
{ 
    //cout << endl; 
    //cout << "Running 'SELECT 'Hello World!' » AS _message'..." << endl; 

    try 
    { 
        sql::Driver *driver; 
        sql::Connection *con; 

    /** 
        * To establish a connection to MySQL Server, 
        * retrieve an instance of sql::Connection from a sql::mysql::MySQL_Driver obj
        */
        driver = get_mysql_driver_instance(); 
        con = driver->connect("tcp://127.0.0.1:3306", "root", "mysql"); 

        /* Example 1: create table and insert records */
   { 
       cout << "To build a connection..." << endl; 
       con = driver->connect("tcp://127.0.0.1:3306", "root", "mysql"); 
       sql::Statement *stmt; 
       sql::ResultSet *res; 
       stmt = con->createStatement(); 
       cout << "To create a table..." << endl; 
       stmt->execute("USE cop2335"); 
       stmt->execute("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS test"); 
       stmt->execute("CREATE TABLE test(id INT, label CHAR(1))"); 
       stmt->execute("INSERT INTO test(id, label) VALUES (1, 'a')"); 
       con->close(); 
}
```

but it didn't work. It gives me errors:

error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) public: _*thiscall sql::SQLString::~SQLString(void)" (*_imp_??1SQLString@sql@@QAE@XZ)

error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) public: __thiscall sql::SQLString::SQLString(char const * const)" (_*imp*??0SQLString@sql@@QAE@QBD@Z)

error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) class sql::mysql::MySQL_Driver * __cdecl sql::mysql::get_driver_instance(void)" (_*imp*?get_driver_instance@mysql@sql@@YAPAVMySQL_Driver@12@XZ) referenced in function "class sql::mysql::MySQL_Driver * __cdecl sql::mysql::get_mysql_driver_instance(void)" (?get_mysql_driver_instance@mysql@sql@@YAPAVMySQL_Driver@12@XZ)

This is my code(which is the one giving the above errors)(without the two lines under the comment //2. ... the code compiles perfectly without any problem):

```
void AddBook::OnBnClickedenterbtnaddbook()
{
sql::mysql::MySQL_Driver *driver; 
    sql::Connection *con; 
//1. get text from dialog textedit box


//2. initialize a DB connection
    driver = sql::mysql::get_mysql_driver_instance();
con = driver->connect("tcp://127.0.0.1:3306", "root", "password");

// 3. update DB
}
```

And I tried it this way too: http://www.nitecon.com/tutorials-articles/develop/cpp/c-mysql-beginner-tutorial/

but it gives me the same errors "Link2019"

Is there somethig Im missing here? Is there another way to connect the database to the project? All help will be welcome. Thanks for reading too.

Answer (score 0):

Unresolved external symbols means, often, that some function has a declaration, but not a definition.

For example

```
Foo.h

class A {
  void foo1();
  void foo2();
}

Foo.cpp

void A::foo2() {
}
```

By the way, in your case, seams that you don't include the lib/dll file that contains the definitions.